# Controle de usuários com permissões em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, segurança

Bom pessoal peguei um sistema desenvolvido em PHP com banco mysql rodando e me passaram a tarefa de criar perfis de usuários ou uma ferramenta para o administrador do sistema colocar o que ele quer que o usuário veja, em java temos o Spring security para essa tarefa, alguém conhece uma solução agradável.

Comment: Eu desenvolvi um projeto, usei o framework CodeIgniter, e fiz toda validação de usuários, de acordo com os módulos que lhe são permitidos... Talvez seria uma boa estratégia usar este framework.

Comment: Ola Xará esse framework ele é procedural ou OO

Comment: Objeto Orientado, muito bom e renderiza bem os forms...

Comment: Seria um sistema para qual segmento?

Comment: acredito que teria que refazer o sistema inteiro isso seria muito oneroso não é?

Comment: Depende... mas dá pra adaptar a idéia dentro do sistema que você já possui... Qual é o segmento dele?

Comment: CMS simples para criação de paginas e colocação de imagens nas paginas do site, mas eles pretendem colocar mais funcionalidades futuramente

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25844/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-andre-martins).

Comment: Use o Laravel 4 ou 5 :). É sem dúvida um dos melhores frameworks em PHP da atualidade :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desenvolva a solução da seguinte forma: Tenha uma tabela de módulos... ao cadastrar o usuário, selecione quais módulos que ele tem permissão e grava tudo numa tabela auxiliar, depois apenas recupere os módulos que são permitidos para aquele idUsuario.

Quando fizer login, registre na session quais são os módulos daquele usuário... e recupere através do foreach(), não esqueça de colocar um if() else () pra verificar se o idUsuario = x tem acesso ao modulo x.

Dúvidas, a disposição.